# How to separate words from a given string and add bits to them

Tags: python, string, random

So. This sounds quite weird but I'm doing it as an excersize to help me learn python!

My problem is;
I want the user to input a sentence say... Hello world and it to output the message with bits attached at the beginning and end for example uhelloay uworlday.
I would also like to programme a way to reverse this so the user inputs uhelloay and it returns with hello.
Quite random but I'd be really grateful if you could help!

Comment: which programming language do you want this?

Comment: @InAFlash: "... to help me learn **python**" I would assume they want it in python.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please show what you have done so far.

Comment: Please show what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

To encode it:

```
my_sentence = input()
piglatin = " ".join(['u' + word + 'ay' for word in my_sentence.split()])
```

To decode:

```
piglatin = " ".join([word[1:-2] for word in my_sentence.split()])
```

you can try to figure out the vowel case yourself :) To keep learning, research the syntax I used and try and work out what each piece is doing to encode and decode the sentence

Answer (score -2):

first, you need to use string.split() so you can get array consist of each world in your string then you can use for and concatenate the additional letters